# SPFx Creating a field by XML with pnp/sp and naming issues

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint

I am creating a field by XML and trying to name it:

```
    .then((lookupList): Promise<any> => {
        console.log("getJobsForLocation | lookupList.Id: ", lookupList.Id);

        let batchCreate = sp.web.createBatch();

        let fieldXml = `<Field Name="FieldName" Type="Lookup" DisplayName="DisplayName" List="{${lookupList.Id}}" ShowField="Title"/>`; 
        ler.list.fields.createFieldAsXml(fieldXml);  

        return batchCreate.execute();
    })
```

My question is, the name is always "DisplayName"

[image]

Shouldn't the field name be "FieldName"?  I would like the field name and display name to be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted on @pnp/sp's github; this is a known issue but can not be resolved.

> This is REST API behavior nuance which we can't amend in the library I'm afraid.

It was suggested after creating the field to update the name:

```
ler.list.fields.inBatch(batchCreate).createFieldAsXml(`<Field Name="${kRegion} DisplayName="${kRegion}" Type="Lookup" List="{${values[1]}}" ShowField="Title" Required="TRUE"/>`);  

batchCreate.execute()
    .then(() => {
        ler.list.fields.getByTitle(kRegion).inBatch(batchUpdate).update({
            Title: removeCamelCase(kRegion)
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the StaticName property :

```
let fieldXml = `<Field Name="FieldName" StaticName="FieldName" Type="Lookup" DisplayName="DisplayName" List="{${lookupList.Id}}" ShowField="Title"/>`;
```